# Is this reputation calculation discrepency a bug or something else?

Tags: bug

The Q/A I see kind of problem is [this](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/102655/34947)
[image]
According to numbers on the left there are 3 positive votes and 2 negative. Which by sample math should make 26 point reputation.

But on the right I see +16 and +8 for this Q/A (which is 24)
Is this a kind of error or I miss something from the SE rules?

Comment: Check out https://photo.stackexchange.com/reputation for a breakdown of your reputation history. Maybe this helps.

Comment: Thank you @mattdm. This page confirm the current situation (which is correct numbers) :)

Answer (score 1):

Certain types of flags (either user submitted or system generated) can result in temporary point reductions that can become permanent if validated.  This appears to likely be what happened here.

Comment: Its not about the point/flags. Its about discrepancy between the information. The same difference is visible in my profile->reputation. Is it fine to open support ticket?

Comment: The point change doesn't show up as vote when it's from the flags sometimes.  You can submit a ticket about it if you want because it is rather unclear, but I'm pretty sure it functioned correctly, the indicators just aren't very good.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I don't think 2 points deserve more attention or support ticket :)

Comment: For the record it seems like kind of strange code behavior. After I delete my post (on other Q/A) I get back those two point.